# Magento Add Two actions to my form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, contact-form

I have a form and on submit of that form one email is going on one ajax action. After the email has been done i want it to redirect to checkout page with one simple product of $100. Please help on this. I cant use the same action.

Comment: do you want this $100 product to e added automatically ?

Comment: yes on click of the submit button i want the customer should go for a checkout with a 100$ product. Cart page should not come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a product to a cart use the following code after you email code in your ajax action

```
<?php
$id = '100'; // Replace id with your product id
$qty = '2'; // Replace qty with your qty
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
?>
```

and after adding product to redirect on checkout page you can use the redirection code like

$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');

please have a look on following url for for some more redirection examples.

https://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/.

hope this will help you.

Comment: This will show the cart page then it will be redirected to the checkout